# tornado authdemo Data not received

Tags: python, tornado

When I run the authdemo in tornado,after auth by google.

```
class AuthHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.GoogleMixin):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        if self.get_argument("openid.mode", None):
            user = yield self.get_authenticated_user()
            self.set_secure_cookie("authdemo_user",
                                   tornado.escape.json_encode(user))
            self.redirect("/")
            return
        self.authenticate_redirect()
```

I get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` on my browser. What happend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/auth/authdemo.py#L37

Add your own cookie_secret.

Comment: I added cookie_secret.

Comment: I notice that you are a Chinese, which country block Google, haven't you try to use some proxy?